# How to remove the 'File Search' dialog page

Tags: eclipse-plugin, eclipse-rcp

Does anybody know how to disable the "File Search" page from the Search Dialog in an Eclipse.

I've just implemented my own `ISearchPage` using the `org.eclipse.search.searchPages` extension. It works perfectly but I wasn't able to remove the "File Seach" dialog page which is shown by default in the Search Dialog.
Any ideeas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems like using the extension `org.eclipse.ui.activities` does the trick.
1.Add extension `org.eclipse.ui.activities` 
2.Add a new `activity` to this extension with id (ex. disable.default.search)
3.Add a new `"activityPatternBinding` to this extension and set the activity id to the id of the `activity` (ex. disable.default.search) and set the pattern to org.eclipse.search.*

Doing this you will remove the "File Search" TabItem in the Search Dialog and also the Search menu from your Applicaiton.