# How to hide tabs in search widget based on activePerspective in Eclipse PDE?

Tags: eclipse-plugin

I'm trying to hide tab created by us in search widget when perspective changed to some other perspective. I trying put some condition in plugin.xml page but didn't succeed in that. Below is the extension I have to hide.

```
<extension
   point="org.eclipse.search.searchPages">
<page
      canSearchEnclosingProjects="true"
      class="com.xxx.udt.ui.MCPFileSearchPage"
      icon="icons/full/search/xxx.png"
      id="com.xxx.udt.ui.page2"
      label="MCP Search"
      showScopeSection="false"
      tabPosition="1">
     <!-- <enabledWhen>
             <with variable="com.xxx.udt.ui.serviceprovider.ShowActions">
                <equals
                      value="showAction">
                </equals>
             </with>
     </enabledWhen>  -->

</page>
<enabledWhen>
  <with variable="com.xxx.udt.ui.serviceprovider.ShowActions">
     <equals value="showAction"/>
  </with>
</enabledWhen>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [remove default search Dialog page from Eclipse RCP App](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12838894/remove-default-search-dialog-page-from-eclipse-rcp-app)

Comment: What are the modifications that you've performed to the plugins.xml file? What is the result of these modifications? This information will understand what you're trying to achieve and where it is going wrong

Answer (score 0):

The `org.eclipse.search.searchPages` extension point does not support hiding pages based on the perspective (or anything else).

Comment: Thanks the response.

Comment: One more question , can we able to hide user defined action under search menu based on the perscpective.

Comment: <extension point="org.eclipse.ui.menus">
     <menuContribution locationURI="menu:org.eclipse.search.menu?after=dialogGroup">
        <command commandId="com.unisys.udt.ui.MCPOpenFileSearchPage"
                 label="MCPFS"
                 mnemonic="%MCPOpenFileSearchPage.mnemonic"
                 icon="icons/full/search/MCPSearchDialog.png"
                 helpContextId="java_search_action_context">
           <visibleWhen>

Comment: <with variable="activeContexts">
                 <iterate operator="or">
                    <equals value="org.eclipse.jdt.ui.SearchActionSet">
                    </equals>
                 </iterate>
              </with>
           </visibleWhen>
        </command>
     </menuContribution>
</extension>

Comment: <extension
         point="org.eclipse.ui.handlers">
         <handler
            commandId="com.unisys.udt.ui.MCPOpenFileSearchPage"
               class="com.unisys.udt.ui.MCPOpenFileSearchPage">
         </handler>
</extension>

Comment: This is a new question, ask a new question.

Answer (score 0):

Steps to hide menu item in search menu :
1>Create a menu contribution.
2>create a command for the same.

```
<extension point="org.eclipse.ui.menus">
 <menuContribution locationURI="menu:org.eclipse.ui.main.menu?after=navigate" >
    <menu label="Search"
          id="org.eclipse.search.menu"
          >


     <command commandId="com.unisys.udt.ui.OpenFileSearchPage"
             label="%action.FileSearch"
             mnemonic="FS"
             icon="icons/full/search/SearchDialog.png" 
            id="com.unisys.udt.ui.OpenFileSearchPage">

      </command> 
      <visibleWhen
                checkEnabled="false">
             <with
                   variable="com.udt.ui.serviceprovider.ShowActions">
                <equals
                      value="showAction">
                </equals>
             </with>
          </visibleWhen> 
       </menu>
 </menuContribution>
 </extension>
```

3>create a handler.

```
<extension
     point="org.eclipse.ui.handlers">
  <handler
        class="com.udt.ui.handlers.OpenFileSearchHandler"
        commandId="com..udt.ui.OpenFileSearchPage">
  </handler>
```

4>create one activitypattern binding for the same.

```
<activityPatternBinding
        activityId="xxx.contributions"
        isEqualityPattern="true"
        pattern="com.udt.ui/com.udt.ui.OpenFileSearchPage">
```